# Split nr into 10s 100s 1000s

Tags: php, integer

Hi I want to split a number into an array using intdiv
the goal is to turn a number like this 1234567890 into

```
Array
    (
        [a] => 123456
        [b] => 78
        [c] => 90
    )
```

---

```
$nr = 1234567890;
$nrSplit = array('a'=>10000,'b'=>100,'c'=>1);
        
$res = array();        
foreach ($nrSplit as $key=>$curr)
{
    $nr =  intdiv($nr, $curr);
    $res [$key]= $nr;
    
}
```

But this is what I get as a result :

```
Array
(
    [a] => 123456
    [b] => 1234
    [c] => 1234
)
```

Comment: You can not do it this way. After `intdiv(1234567890 / 10000)`, you are left with only `123456`, the rest of the information is _lost_ at this point already, because you overwrite your $nr variable with this value.

Comment: You either need to do this in steps that build on each other, or via a combination of modulo and integer division. (modulo 100 gets you the 90. modulo 10000 and then int-div’ed by 100, gets you the 78, etc.)

Comment: Simple pencil and paper would tell you that calculation wont generate the results you say you want

Comment: @CBroe ok thank you I thought I could do it during a loop like in python

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible in a loop? You just have to continue working with the remainder, not the result of the division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you just need to reset the *dividend*(`$nr`) by removing from  *dividend* the part you store in `$res` array.

```php
$nr = 1234567890;
$nrSplit = array('a'=>10000,'b'=>100,'c'=>1);// 'c' <- 1 not 10 to get 90 not 9.
foreach ($nrSplit as $key=>$curr)
{
    $n = $nr;// just for demonstration.

    $res [$key] = intdiv($nr, $curr);
    $nr %= $curr; //$nr = $nr % $curr;

    echo $n.' / '.$curr.' => '.$res[$key].'<br>';
    echo $n.' % '.$curr.' => '.$nr.'<hr>';
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

**Output:**

```
/*
1234567890 / 10000 => 123456
1234567890 % 10000 => 7890

7890 / 100 => 78
7890 % 100 => 90

90 / 1 => 90
90 % 1 => 0

Array
(
    [a] => 123456
    [b] => 78
    [c] => 90
)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach` to iterate and than use `/` & `%`

```
$res = array(); 
foreach($nrSplit as $div){
  $nr = isset($previous) ? $previous : $nr;
  $res[] = (int) ($nr / $div);// $res[] = intdiv($nr, $div);
  $previous = $nr%$div;
}
print_r($res);
```

Live example :- https://3v4l.org/Sq9iB